# All mounts and commands via terminal inaccessible when single mount is inaccessible

Tags: mount

I've noticed that when I take one of my servers offline, my other mounts (not related to the offline server) and mount related commands hang in CLI. I can still navigate them via the GUI, but commands such as ls, and cd hang when executed on the parent and child directories of my still mounted drives. Even df hangs. I am still able to execute lsblk.

Once I manually umount the drive operations return to normal. Should I be automating the umount or is there a clean less manual way to remedy this? Linux is not my native OS so forgive me if this is obvious. I'm used to Windows handling this type of behavior for me.

I'm using `CentOS 3.10.0-514.26.2.el7.x86_64`

Comment: I don't understand the sentence “when I take one of my servers offline mount directories (via terminal) and mount related commands hang”. Is it missing a word? Did you unmount something, or is a mounted filesystem (what filesystem type — NFS? Samba? …) temporarily unreachable, or what?

Comment: Ah, I see. What filesystem do you use (NFS, Samba, …)?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to check your NFS mount options in the /etc/fstab file.  I usually use "rw,bg,hard,vers=3" (that's for NFSV3). I had a similar issue, I fixed it by moving the NFS export to the SAN... which almost never gets rebooted.